# How to change databind using dropdownlist inside gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to change databind based on dropdownlist selectedvalue inside gridview? I have tried use string and it work, how can i change the datatabind on selcted row?
[image: How I've arrived here]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with GridViewRowDataBound event like this.

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Try This
           DropDownlist ddl =((DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlUOM"));
           Label lblCargo = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblNameOfCargo"));
           if(ddl.SelectedValue == "Barrel")
           {
             lblCargo.Text = "test";
           }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i change the databind of row that the ddl has changed?

Comment: Do you want to change the data of gridview by the change in ddl?

Comment: yes, and the ddl is inside a gridview. I want some data that at same row with ddl changed based on ddl selected value..

Answer (score 0):

on selected index changed event of ddl try something like this.

```
DropDownList ddlUOM = (DropDownList)sender;
GridViewRow rpItem = ddlUOM .NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
Label lblCargo = ((Label)rpItem.FindControl("lblNameOfCargo"));
if(ddlUOM.SelectedValue == "Barrel")
  {
    lblCargo.Text = "test";
  }
```